# static variable in static methods

Tags: c++, class, methods, static

I woudld like to create a shared library.
I have a class full of static methods. You know that you can call static variable in static methods so I created static variables too.

```
class TryClass{
    public:
       static void method0(string s);
       static void method1();
       static void method2();
    private:
       static string name;
};
```

`method1` and `method2` need to share the string name, setted in `method0`. The problem is that I should initialize string name outside my class (in source file), in this way:

```
string TryClass::name= "filename";
```

but I need to initilize it in the `method0` method.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: not clear what is the problem. You have to initalize it in the cpp, but `method0` can assign a new value to it

Comment: Why can't you trash what it's already been initialised to when you run `method0`?

Comment: The above does not compile, you're missing return types.

Comment: btw your code has syntax errors and why do you have a class with only static methods? (smells like you are trying to imitate java)

Comment: fixed the question sorry

Comment: still not clear what is the problem. Please show the actual code that causes you a problem and error messages if there are. Also read about [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all correct your code and try this in your class.

```
static void method0(string s)
{
     TryClass::name = "hello";
}
```

So, you can easily share string name in `method1` and `method2`.

Comment: maybe `void` return type instead of `string` ?